# converting ordinary Differential Equations to Polar Coordinate system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, computational-mathematics

I want to convert this system into Polar coordinates

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = y,\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -\mu(x^2 + y^2 - 1)y - x$$

I know in order to convert this ODE system in polar coordinates, you would use these formulas, $$x \,dx/dt+y\,dy/dt=r\,dr/dt,\\ \,ydx/dt-x\,dy/dt=-r^2\,dθ/dt.$$  Here is what I have so far,
$$xy+y(-μ(r^2-1)y-x)=r\,dr/dt,\\ y^2-x(-μ(r^2-1))*y-x.$$
Can someone please tell me how I convert the system of $dy/dt$ and $dx/dt$ into polar coordinates?

Comment: Did I correctly convert your equations? You need to use LaTeX to format your mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a polar coordinates relationship linked to stability by adding

$$
\cases{
x x'= x y\\
y y'=-x y - \mu y^2(x^2+y^2-1)
}\Rightarrow \frac 12(x^2+y^2)'=-\mu y^2(x^2+y^2-1)
$$

and now using the polar coordinates

$$
\cases{
x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta
}
$$

we get

$$
\frac 12(r^2)' = -\mu r^2\sin^2\theta(r^2-1)
$$

NOTE

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot x\\ \dot y \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & r\cos\theta \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot r\\ \dot \theta \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}r\sin\theta\\ -\mu(r^2-1)r\sin\theta-r\cos\theta\end{array}\right)
$$

and finally

$$
\cases{
\dot r = -\mu  r \left(r^2-1\right) \sin ^2\theta\\
\dot\theta = -\mu  \left(r^2-1\right) \sin\theta\cos\theta-1
}
$$

Comment: So, what I did is I did use =cos, =sin. I basically did implicit differentiation with those equations. Then I substituted those equations into  the system =,=−(2+2−1)−, then, the final answer I get is r'=(r^(2)-1)*r*sin^(2) and '=(r^(2)-1)*sincos+1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remember that $x=r.cos(\theta)$ and $y=r.sin(\theta)$ so $dx=cos(\theta).dr-r.sin(\theta).d\theta$ by the chain rule and the same applies for $y$. Once you have them solved it is only needed to substitute in the original equation and you are done.